# I am trying to show hide a dynamically added component inside a parent component onClick

Tags: angular

I am trying to hide a child component generated dynamically from a parent component `onClick` using template and `*ngIf`

Tried to use `*ngIf` but the child component is always showing even.

(click)="checkStatus($event)" changes the status

```
<div class="contentColumn">
  <div *ngIf="item.content !== ''">
    <i class="" [class.icon-hover]="status ? 'clickChevronToShow' : 'clickChevronToHide'"
    (click)="checkStatus($event)" [ngClass]="status ? 'iconArrow fa fa-angle-double-up' : 'iconArrow fa fa-angle-double-down'"></i>
  </div>
  <span class="iconClose" [class.icon-hover]="clickIconToClose" (click)="onClickIcon($event)"></span>
</div>

<div *ngIf="status" [@enterAnimation]>
  <div class="sn-content" *ngIf="contentIsTemplate else regularContent">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content; context: item.context"></ng-container>
  </div>
  <ng-template #regularContent>
    <div class="sn-content" [innerHTML]="content"></div>
    <div [hidden]="!status" class="sn-content" component-host></div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

The innerHtml of content show hide ok.
but the next one component-host is not.

Comment: there is no `ngif` or `onClick` anywhere in your code, please provide an example to your problem

Comment: It would be great, if you provide us with a demo of you problem.Use this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvdfdc

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the child component based on the a variable from parent component, you need to pass a property from parent component to child component (use @Input property). Based on that property you have to write ngIf statement with that property.